# Was bedeutet „einmal zu oft“?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase

**Einmal zu oft** scheint ein fester Ausdruck zu sein.
Die Bedeutung der einzelnen Wörter ist klar, allerdings erschließt sich mir die Bedeutung im Kontext nicht.

> 1. Ich habe *einmal zu oft* erfolglos nach einem passenden Script oder Plugin für den trueSpace Workspace gestöbert.
> 2. Wer also lieber *einmal zu oft* davonlief als einmal zu wenig, geriet zwar häufiger außer Atem, kam aber ungeschoren davon.

Was bedeutet *einmal zu oft*?

Comment: Das erste Zitat zeigt den Sinn ganz gut: Einmal zu wenig weglaufen bedeutet, dass man nicht wegläuft, obwohl es nötig gewesen wäre, "einmal zu oft" demenstprechend, dass man wegläuft obwohl es nicht nötig war. Da sich das nötig/unnötig meist erst hinterher herauskristallisiert, ist es eine Einstellungsfrage - Adrenalin-Junkies laufen einmal zu wenig weg (und sind dann [von was auch immer ] betroffen) - Ängstliche laufen eher einmal zu oft weg (und verpassen dann einmal was (wenn etwas Gutes passiert), sind aber auch nicht betroffen wenn etwas schief geht ) - bitte präzisiere dein Unverständnis

Answer (score 5):

Eigentlich ist der Sinn der Phrase klar, daher versuche ich es mit einem Beispiel zu erklären:

Jemand spielt mit einem Revolver russisches Roulett. Fünfmal hat er bereits den Abzug betätigt, ohne dass sich ein Schuss gelöst hat. Beim sechsten Mal stirbt er.

Er hätte spätestens nach der fünften Runde aufhören müssen, dann hätte er überlebt. Er hat aber **einmal zu oft** mit seinem Leben gespielt, und nun ist er tot.

Comment: Das sechste Mal ist kein Spiel, sondern Suizid. Abgesehen davon, dass schon die ersten fünf Versuche kein Spiel sind, dass ich spielen würde.

Comment: @Philipp: Erstens gibt es Revolver mit unterschiedlich vielen Kammern. Da gibt es welche, die nur 5 Kammern haben, und welche, die man mit bis zu 30 Patronen beladen kann. Zweitens drehst ja jedesmal die Trommel bevor du den Abzug betätigst. Die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass sich ein Schuss löst ist bei jedem Spiel gleich. Die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass du mit einem sechsschüssigen Revolver sechs Runden überlebst, beträgt 33,4%.

Comment: Natürlich, der berühmte 7-Kammer-Revolver :) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagant_M1895) Aber die Wahrscheinlichkeit, das sechste Mal zu überleben, wenn man bereits fünfmal gedrückt hat, ist natürlich eher gering... Es sei denn, man nutzt den Henrion, Dassy & Heuschen Revolver, der zwanzig Kammern hat. Trotzdem ein blödes Spiel.

Comment: @Philipp: Du unterliegst einem Denkfehler! Die Wahrscheinlichkeit das hundertste Mal zu überleben wenn man bereits 99-mal abgedrückt hat, ist **exakt** gleich hoch, wie beim allerersten Mal, nämlich (bei einem 6-Schüssigen Revolver) 5/6 = 83,33%. Aber die Wahrscheinlichkeit, so weit zu kommen, das man das hundertste Mal abdrücke kann, die ist verschwindend gering (ungefähr ein Millionstel Prozent).

Comment: Ich kenne natürlich das Ziegenproblem (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziegenproblem).
Aber wenn du die Wahrscheinlichkeiten addierst, musst du trotzdem auf 1 kommen. Bei einem idealen Spiel (eine von sechs Kammern des Revolvers ist geladen, es gibt keine Ladehemmung, man drückt so lange ab, bis sechsmal gedrückt wurde oder sich ein Schuss löst etc.) ist die Wahrscheinlichkeit, keinen Schuss zu lösen, 0 %. Das bringt das Spielprinzip mit sich.

Comment: @Philipp: Nocheinmal: Du vergisst, dass beim russischen Roulett die Trommel des Revolvers **vor jeder Betätigung des Abzugs** gedreht wird. Deine Rechnung würde stimmen, wenn man die Trommel nur einmal dreht, und dann (bei einem 6-Kammern-Revolver) sechsmal abdrückt. - Und das hat nichts mit dem Ziegenproblem zu tun (außer dass beide Probleme Aufgaben aus dem Bereich der Kombinatorik sind).

Comment: Oh, ich wusste tatsächlich nicht, dass die Trommel vor jedem Abzug randomisiert wird.

Answer (score 2):

Die Beispielsätze sind schlechte Beispiele. Ein Muttersprachler würde dies wohl nicht so ausdrücken. Beide Beispiele sollte mit einem einfachen "zu oft" geschrieben werden.

> Wer also lieber zu oft davonlief, war zwar ziemlich oft außer Atem.
>
> Ich habe zu oft erfolglos nach einem passenden Script oder Plugin für den trueSpace Workspace gestöbert

"Einmal zu oft" impliziert einen erheblich negativen Effekt oder Schaden.

> Er lief einmal zu oft davon und galt nun als Feigling.
>
> Ich habe einmal zu oft Software heruntergelanden und mir eine Virus eingefangen.

Comment: Bitte möglichst keine Code-Formatierung (außer für Programmcode), der fehlende Zeilenumbruch macht den Text zumindest auf kleinen Displays wie Smartphones unlesbar. Danke!

Answer (score 1):

**Definition:** Sei *h(x)* die Häufigkeit des Stattfindens eines Vorganges *x*, und sei *n* eine feste obere Grenze, bis zu der etwas stattfinden soll. Ist *h(x) = n + 1*, dann hat *x* **einmal zu oft** stattgefunden.

Comment: Die obere Grenze ist aber meistens nicht fest. Wie oft darf man bei einem klassischen Konzert laut furzen bevor man rausgeworfen wird? Wenn man am nächsten Tag einen Furz weniger loslässt, kann man dann mit Sicherheit davon ausgehen, unbehelligt zu bleiben?

Comment: Zum Furz-Beispiel: Für das nahe Umfeld des Akteurs spielt sehr wahrscheinlich der Faktor Geruch eine bedeutendere Rolle ;)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ist denn das wichtig? Die Grenze kann situationsbedingt sehr variabel und (dem Betroffenen im Voraus) vollkommen unbekannt sein.

Comment: Recht witzlos auf eine Frage es Deutsch Lerndenden mit einer (pseudo) mathematischen Definition zu antworten.